# View currently published page in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am making edits to a client's Sharepoint site.

I checked out the page, made all the changes required, checked it back in, and am waiting on their go-ahead to publish.

I want to double-check that certain elements are the same as they were before I started editing. Generally I would go to site contents > pages > version history of the page I am working on, and look at the currently published version (because, as an editor, it seems to only show me the unpublished draft when I am on the page URL).

Tried to do that today and am getting an error: Sorry, something went wrong
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904.... Insightful and intuitive Microsoft error - well done guys (NOT).

Is there any other way that is more straightforward to just view what is currently published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to either log on as a test account that has only got read only permissions, or to ask one of your colleagues that doesn't have edit permissions to browse to the page and you can see what they see.

Version history, while is helpful when you need to roll back, won't show changes to web parts or other hidden elements when viewing it, so it's not always that helpful when using it for a case like yours.

As a side note, to log in as another user in SP2013, append this to your URL: http://yoursite/**_layouts/15/closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true**

Comment: Neat tricks. Unfortuantely, our client is very stingy with providing accounts and we only have one edit account. Generally, if I want to log in as a viewer simultaneously, I use another browser.